# javascript: listen for postMessage events from specific iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, postmessage

I have multiple iframes in a page. Now I have one `message` event listener for the page, which gets the messages from all of the iframes. I have a workaround to know from which iframe the message is coming.

I would like to make event listeners for each iframe separately. Is this possible?

Comment: Don't think that is possible. The window can receive `message` events from anywhere. If you have a workaround, that is probably ok.

Comment: Just for the sake of curiosity, how do you do your workaround?

Comment: I know this is super old, but if you have control of the framed content, you can use the [Channel Messaging API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Channel_Messaging_API) to set up distinct channels with separate event listeners for each frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Best you can do is to have a single handler that routes received messages to helper handlers based on the origin of the message sender.

Comment: Can be done by setting a unique name attribute for each iframe. Then inside iframe window.name is the name of the iframe and can be send with postMessage.

Comment: The comment above should be an answer it's the best solution of all.

Comment: The (currently) highest rated answer shows that it is possible by applying a source filter to the event.

Answer (score 105):

You must listen on the global `message` event of the `window` object, but you can filter the source iframe using the [`source`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessageEvent/source) property of [`MessageEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessageEvent).

Example:

```
const childWindow = document.getElementById('test-frame').contentWindow;
window.addEventListener('message', message => {
    if (message.source !== childWindow) {
        return; // Skip message in this event listener
    }

    // ...
});
```

Comment: It didn't always work for me, for some reason. So instead of `message.source` I had to use `message.target[0]` then it worked like a charm....

Answer (score 11):

If the `src` attribute of each iframe is unique then you can try this:

On the child:

```
function sendHeight() {
  // sends height to parent iframe
  var height = $('#app').height();
  window.parent.postMessage({
    'height': height,
    'location': window.location.href
  }, "*");
}

$(window).on('resize', function() {
  sendHeight();
}).resize();
```

On the parent:

```
$(window).on("message", function(e) {
    var data = e.originalEvent.data;
    $('iframe[src^="' + data.location + '"]').css('height', data.height + 'px');
});
```

The child sends it's height and URL to the iframe parent using `postMessage()`. The parent then listens for that event, grabs the iframe with that URL and sets the height to it.

Comment: I guess I could strip out the height bits. Shall I?

Comment: I think the OP simply wants individual eventListeners for each iframe, but it'd be useless since multiple eventListeners listening on any iframe would be a duplicate because it's the same event. Any duplicated eventListeners are just wasted spice since only one will work whilst any duplicates will be ignored.

Answer (score 9):

Actually you can. Add a unique name attribute to each iframe. iframe name is passed down to the contentWindow. So inside iframe window.name is the name of the iframe and you can easily send it in post message.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `e.originalEvent.origin` to identify the iframe.

**On the iframe child:**

```
window.parent.postMessage({
  'msg': 'works!'
}, "*");
```

**On the iframe parent:**

*Javascript*

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  console.log(e.origin); // outputs "http://www.example.com/"
  console.log(e.data.msg); // outputs "works!"
  if (e.origin === 'https://example1.com') {
    // do something
  } else if (e.origin === 'https://example2.com'){
    // do something else
  }
}, false);
```

*jQuery*

```
$(window).on('message', function(e) {
  ...
}, false);
```

So `origin` contains the protocol and domain from which the `postMessage()` was fired from. It does not include the URI. This technique assume all iframes have a unique domain.

Comment: Does `e.originalEvent.origin` return a url as a result of being a serialized string? I'm not all that familiar with jQuery and all I find on that is it returns certain properties inside an objectEvent that was wrapped up for convenience by jQuery. So `origin` actually can show an event's `location.protocol + location.hostname`?

Answer (score 1):

One way of detecting where the message came from is by checking which iframe is focused or for my specific scenario which iframe is visible.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented an iframe proxy.
Iframe with in an iframe ( nesting them ).
Each iFrame proxy creates it's own unique I'd.
Than every message that is sent from child iframe to parent is gets an added field of the iframe proxy I'd.
In the parent you then route every message from the iframeproxy to it's dedicated handler.
This mechanism separate iframes perfectly

Comment: You should probably show some code (or at least pseudocode) for that.